# Find index of element in list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm new to Scheme, and I don't know where to start with this. I want to write a Scheme function, which takes two parameters, a list `lst` and an atom `atm`, and returns the index of the first location where `atm` occurs in the list.  The location index is 1-relative. If `atm` does not occur in the list, the function returns `n + 1`, where `n` is the length of the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a skeletal solution. Replace all the `<???>` with appropriate items.

```
(define (index-of lst x)
  (cond ((null? lst) <???>)
        ((eq? <???> x) <???>)
        (else (+ (index-of <???> x) 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You make an auxiliary procedure or named let with your argument list and a index initialized to 1.

If the list is empty or current car is the element you are looking for you return index or else you recurse with the `cdr` and increase index by 1.